# Log file processing

Tags: linux, bash

[image]
I have a log file like this; I can get NOW=HOUR=`date +'%H'`

I can get login time in hour with something like cat file | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d: -f1

Is there a way I can compare the login times in hours in the file against current time in hour  and say if the login hour is > 5 hours and display the record only matching that criteria.

Say its 3pm which is 15 hours, we would not like to display below as log in times are less than 5 hours

11:26:16     Login.Success     yden8703        gkU3Qx4iiWPVMrV

12:26:24     Login.Success      pxia9495        2OVvMrAmgRAOZyJ

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want. - How to handle entries from previous days? Is there a lower limit or also an upper limit to filter? Is the current time (hour) related to the actual value(s) of the limit(s)? Do you need accuracy of only full hours? - For one simple interpretation see below in the answer.

Comment: `notepad` - how quaint! :)  - real text (embedded as code) is better. as we can copy and paste it for testing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -v argsec=$((5*60*60)) '
        BEGIN{ nowsec=systime() }
      { logsec=mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g",$1" "$2));
        if(nowsec-logsec<=argsec) print;
      }' logfile
```

Your could put the conversion of 5 hours to seconds in awk's `BEGIN` block, but it seems more flexitple to have it in an arg variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get the login lines from a logfile that have an hour greater than 05:00:00 in column 2 try:

```
awk '$2+0>=5' logfile
```